# What episode of the original Spider-Man cartoon is this popular Internet meme format from?

Tags: marvel, cartoon, episode-identification

This is a series of images from *Spider-Man*, the 1967-1970 animated TV series. What episode are these from?

[image: meme format with Peter reading a book on his bed then an over shoulder view of a blank page and him pointing at it and then a close up of his confused/shocked face]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It’s from [The Revenge of Dr. Magneto](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0824206/) (~6 minutes in):

[image: Peter looking at the book and the page says Magneto]

The name of the book is “Who’s Who in Science”.

Comment: Magnetism science

Comment: Oh it was his birthday 8 days ago.

Comment: @Oni I could see someone getting a PhD for research involving magnetism, especially in the fields of medicine or electronics. It probably wouldn't be written as "specialist in magnetism science", but it was a children's show, so a simplification of the language used to be suitable to the audience is reasonable.

Comment: @nick012000  "specialist in magnetism" and "science hall of fame nominee 1965" makes perfect sense. There are plenty of real-world organisations with a "science hall of fame".